# Source vs spring

Tags: meaning

In the meaning *"an issue of water from the earth, taking the form, on the surface, of a small stream or standing as a pool or small lake"* (from [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spring?s=t)), what is the **difference** between **spring** and **source**? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: The difference is that a ***spring*** identifies a spot where (underground) water rises to the surface. Feasibly, that water may rapidly evaporate or drain back underground without really "going" anywhere. But if the water flows above ground, perhaps augmented by other springs, and eventually becomes, say, a *river*, you might describe the original spring as the ***source*** of that river (i.e. - *where it came from*). You wouldn't normally call it a "source" in isolation - only in reference to whatever it's the source ***of***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in usage.

A *spring* is the upwelling of water from underground, with a visible flow.
A *source* is the commencement of a river or stream, it may be a lake or pond with no perceptible inflow.

In more detail:  At a *spring*, you see water visibly issuing from the ground.  It may then flow into a pond or may flow away in a stream.  The water may be warm, depending upon the depth from which it comes.  The rate of flow doesn't matter.

A river's *source* is simply the point at which it starts.  This can be a pond that fills from water flowing down from a hill, the flow into this pond is not necessarily noticeable as a flow.

So, a *spring* may be the source of a river but a source is not necessarily a *spring*.